# Use result from jdbc request for the next request

Tags: jdbc, jmeter

I am using JDBC to query on azure sql in JMeter. I was able to successfully get the response. see below

otp
100940

In the Result variable name the value is OTP

My next step in Http request POST method, see below

```
{
    "id": ${requestId},
    "otp": "${OTP}",
    "requestId": "123456"
}
```

as you can see otp is parameterized.

But in actual request see below;

```
POST data:
{
    "id": 506,
    "otp": "[{otp=100940}]",
    "requestId": "123456"
}
```

how can I concatenate so that I only get the actual otp value without the [{otp=}]

Comment: Change the datatype of `otp` so it isn't an array or collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can add [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) to extract number from OTP variable

Choose `Apply To:` JMeter Variable and write `OTP` and use regular expression as:

```
otp=(\d+)
```

And use Template `$1$` and Match No. `1`

> JMeter Variable Name to use - extraction is to be applied to the contents of the named variable

Comment: Thanks, I tried your instruction but otp=(\d+) does not work

Comment: @yngielkoh did you saved it in different variable as otpValue and then use it as `${otpValue}`? Did you put extractor under JDBC Request?

Answer (score 0):

If your response is this `otp 100940`, use below Regular Expression to extract it:

[image]

Now, you can use anywhere `OTP value using ${OTP} variable`

```
{
    "id": ${requestId},
    "otp": "${OTP}",
    "requestId": "123456"
}
```